# Installing DSpace on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: linux, postgresql, dspace

I found a tutorial to install DSpace on linux. Everithing runs fine with the exception of  enabling the pgcrypto extension.

The tutorial proposes to use this line:

```
`psql –username=postgres dspace -c “CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;”`
```

But running these commands, the following issues occur:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "EXTENSION" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "pgcrypto" ignored
psql: error: could not connect to server: invalid connection option "–username"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type `psql --help`, you'll easily find the answer:

> -U, --username=USERNAME  database user name (default: "postgres")

like almost every linux program, psql has full name argument preceded by double dash.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know, I have a really short time using linux.